# Get all links inside iframe and add blank target attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to retrieve all href elements on a page that is an iframe?

Meaning, I have a page that is iframing a page from different site.  What I am showing in the iframe contains a number of links (href tags).

Is it possible to add a TARGET attribute of BLANK to all links inside the iframe?  The links are buried inside a number of divs and tables, so I need to be able to recursively add the attribute inside many nested tables/divs.

**EDIT:
Added screenshot to show extra characters needed to be removed:**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the iframe src it's on the same domain you can easily access it by using document.getElementById("frameID").document and manipulate that.

If it's a different domain you may consider link the iframe to a script in your own domain, and make that script download the data from the remote domain and print out:)

**myHTMLpage.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
        <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ifr").load(function () {
                var ifr = document.getElementById("ifr")
                var anchors = ifr.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("a");
                for (var i in anchors) {
                    anchors[i].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="myOwnSite.aspx" width="900px" height="600px" id="ifr" ></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**myOwnSite.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyOwnSite.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyOwnSite" %>
```

**myOwnSite.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;


public partial class MyOwnSite : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Response.Write(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://theExternalSiteHere.com"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is on a different domain.  Can you elaborate some on linking the iframe to a script on my domain so I can download the data and print it?  I am not understanding entirely.  Thanks

Comment: You have the page with the iframe. The iframes src attribute  points to a php or asp script on your own site. That script will download  the page that should be in the iframe and echo/response.write it out. Now you have the correct html, on your own domain.    I'm on my phone so I can't give a code sample. But if it still doesn't make sense I can provide you a sample in half an hour :)

Comment: Almost...it is just not adding the target attribute to the href tags.  I have tried your code and using jquery.

Comment: Try the updated html page now.. There was some errors. I've tried it in Chrome 16.0.9, and it works! Testet on this page; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx for curiosity

Comment: That works perfectly.  Thanks so much!  One more thing - for some reason I see a bunch of Â characters inside of my iframe.  Using the suggested solution, how can I hide those character or replace them with an empty string?

Comment: I updated my original post to show a screenshot of the extra characters my iframe is showing.  How can I hide or replace all of these extra characters found inside the iframe?

Comment: Looks like an encoding problem. Try read about character encoding in html :)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `<base target="_blank">` inside the head tag of your iframe.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible if the site inside the iframe is not on your domain which according to your description seems to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

var anchors= document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("a");
                for (var i in anchors) {
                    anchors[i].target = "_blank"; //.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
                }

I have IE8. The script for IE 6 and IE 7 can be different.