# ASP.net Passing Links from Page to Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to display a page into an IFrame. 
The IFrame is displayed into a fancyBox overlay popup.
I have a list with the http links (gets compiled at runtime and it constantly changes).
Using a global variable I can access the list with the links.
But the http link in the list must match the link I have clicked.
If I can even get the link which I have clicked it will also be enough (the link brings up a fancyBox popup so it doesn't actually bring up a new page so to speak)
How to do that?

Comment: have tried saving to session variables or passing the information via query strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write some tricky code to achieve this, main goal is to edit the dynamically added page content by adding wrapper tag (with onclick event) around all the links, writing javascript to be called using that wrapper to findout which link has been clicked,

You can try this by doing following steps

1) Get the content of IFrame , using the following JQuery code you can get the content of IFrame

```
var $currentIFrame = $('#myIFrame');
var content = $currentIFrame.contents();
```

2) Now manupulate these content by finding all the links inside that page and wrapping them with a tag that should have onclick event e.g. span , you have to write some javascript function to fire on a link if user clicks it.

see the following link for how to manipulate content

[Get all links inside iframe and add blank target attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890699/get-all-links-inside-iframe-and-add-blank-target-attribute)

Comment: The trick is that I need the value of the link just clicked to create the IFrame http link to display.